# Office addin does not persist with workbook across browsers

Tags: office365, office-js, office365-apps

Me and my team have developed a taskpane addin for online excel and we have published it on office365 domain. Now, when we open an online excel workbook and insert the addin, the addin is available in the ribbon. Here, once we close the document, log out from office365 and log in again the addin is available with the saved document. But if we change the browser the addin isn't available on the same saved document and needs to be re-inserted. So suppose we have logged in into our Microsoft account using Chrome, we log out and again log in with Firefox into our Microsoft account with the same credentials the taskpane doesn't showup in the ribbon. And then if we again log in using Chrome, it shows up into the ribbon. Same issue also reflects if you change the machine.
P.S Our office addin is available under "My Organisations" tab in Insert Office Addin dialog. Does anybody have any insights about this?

Answer (score 0):

With add-in commands (buttons on the Ribbon) the add-in is not "Inserted" from a users point of view, its "installed" on the given device (browser==device in this context); I know, the fact that add-ins/store are under the Insert Tab doesn't help but we are looking to address that soon. So, currently the add-in needs to be manually installed on a per device basis, in the future it will be automatically installed across all devices provided the user logs-in with the same account.

Also worth nothing that you are using a way to deploy add-ins with commands that is not supported (via a SharePoint Catalog); it happens to work for Online clients but it won't work if you try to use it in other platforms like Windows or the Mac. [Centralized Deployment](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-new-Admin-Center-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE) is the technology that you should probably take a look at.